# Regular Expression Validator for year in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a textbox which has academic year as the input. It can be of the format either 
**2013-14** or **2013-2014**. How do I use a regular expression validator for this?

Comment: Regex is great for text patterns but bad for calculations: it's impossible (or at least very impractical) to specify that after "2013" only a "14" (as "13+1") is allowed. Use a custom validator for that.

Comment: Yes I agree if need year- year+ 1 you need additional validation for business logic

Comment: If you have a very limited range of values, you might consider using a dropdown of specific (hardcoded or calculated) values, instead of a free-format textbox+validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue..The code is like so ..

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="txtAcademicYearName_RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAcademicYearName" ErrorMessage="Enter academic year name in format YYYY-YY" ValidationExpression="(\b19|\b20)\d\d-\d\d" ForeColor="Red" Display="None"  ValidationGroup="AcademicYear"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex

```
^(\d{4}-(\d{2}|\d{4}))$
```

and how to use regex validator you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx)

if you want to validate that the second year equal to first plus 1 this is business logic, and should be validated on server side, after regex validation passed on client side. For example on client side you can validate that user enter correct format in input Textbox with regex above using this validation does not allow to input incorrect string, after this validation passed on server side you can parse input string and validate logic that second year should be greater then first

Comment: Hi, I can enter any year as a matter of fact. Will your code work in any scenario?

Comment: What did you mean any year? from your question I understood that the format is 2014-15 or 2014-2015 4 and 2 or 4 digits if not give more examples

Comment: Your regex will allow "1234-98". I suspect that it must be: "year in 4 digits" dash "year+1 in two digits". And maybe even "a year not too far from present".

Comment: I can enter a year in format either 2013-14 or 2013-2014. That is it. I should not allow any other format.

Comment: format is 4 digits year and 2 or 4 digits year if second year should be greater than first +1 I think this is business logic, and you should validate this after validate with regex and parse the input string

Comment: Ok, shall try this. Thanks!

Comment: and of course the business logic you should validate on server side input errors with regex on client side in this case you will have both of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression

`^([0-9]{4})[./-]+([0-9]{2})$` **// result 2012-13 or 2012/13**

`^([0-9]{4})[./-]+([0-9]{4})$` **// result 2012-2013 or 2012/2013**